Is there any way to verify oracle SQL database connection and error handling?
Recently I'm configuring Oracle SQL Databse with node.js.
I'm able to established DB connection successfully and able to execute query.
My db connection sample query is:
import * as oracledb from 'oracledb';

export class OracleSQL {
    private static conn;

    static async connect() {
        this.conn = await oracledb.getConnection({
            connectString: "host:port/schema",
            user     :  "username",
            password :  "********"
        });
        // TODO: add some condition to verify database connected successfully
        // if (connection is established) {
            console.log('Database connected successfully');
            return true;
        // }
        
        // TODO: if connection not established for any reason and throwing error
        //       How to handle this error ? 
        //       is that a simple "Try...Catch" method or some other way ?
    }

    static async query(queryStr) {
        // TODO: add some condition to verify connection is still alive or not
        if (!this.conn) {
            let res = await this.connect()
            if (res) {
                return await this.conn.execute(queryStr);
            }
        } else {
            return await this.conn.execute(queryStr);
        }
    }

    static async close() {
        // TODO: add some condition to verify connection already established or not
        // if (connection is established) {
                await this.conn.close()
                .then(() => {
                    console.log('Database disconnected successfully');
                    this.conn = null;
                    return true;
                });
        // }
    }
}

I want add two objective here:

How to check my connection is established(alive) or not ?
How handle error ? Is there any db event handler ?

I have cheeked the Node.js Oracle Connection, npm oracledb documents. But did not found any valuable information.

After lots of research I found,
Oracle DB connection object have a property, conn._impl.nscon.connected, which contains boolean value of connection establishment.
import * as oracledb from 'oracledb';

const conn = await oracledb.getConnection({
                               connectString: "host:port/schema",
                               user     :  "username",
                               password :  "********"
                          });
if ( conn._impl.nscon.connected ) {
    console.log('Database connected successfully');
}

Is that a valid way to verify connection is established or alive status ?
I'm not sure. Have you any idea ?

Any interface prefixed with _, such as _impl, tends to be private and is not intended to be used directly as it will be undocumented and may change between versions without any warning (because it is private and not meant to be used). If you use it then your code may break without warning when you upgrade to later version of the database driver.

exactly right @MT0.  That's why I asked. I need some other way to validate this....

Create a ticket at node-oracledb: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1681

Hi, I believe this issue has been resolved.

I would recommend to use try/catch method to verify the connection establishment and for error handling
import * as oracledb from 'oracledb';

export class OracleSQL {
    private static conn;

    static async connect() {
        try{
            this.conn = await oracledb.getConnection({
                connectString: "host:port/schema",
                user     :  "username",
                password :  "********"
            });
            console.log('Database connected successfully');
            return true;
        }catch(e){
            console.log('Database connection failed, Reason:',e.message);
            return false;
        }
    }

    static async query(queryStr) {
        if (!this.conn) {
            let res = await this.connect()
            if (res) {
                return await this.conn.execute(queryStr);
            }
        } else {
            return await this.conn.execute(queryStr);
        }
    }

    static async close() {
        if (this.conn) {
                try{
                    await this.conn.close()
                    console.log('Database disconnected successfully');
                    this.conn = null;
                    return true;
                }catch(e){
                    console.log("Database disconnection failed, Reason", e.message);
                }
        }
    }
}


I generally hate to use try...cache. DB should have some configuration to handle error. Also, this.conn is an object of DB connection, this is not a proper way to verify alive connection . . . I already try this . . . I need answer in proper structure way ....  Thanks for your  suggestion...

The node-oracledb documentation is available here - https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html.
You can use connection.isHealthy() to check the health status of a connection.
You can use connection.ping to see if a connection is currently usable and the network to the database is valid. Note that ping() function requires a round trip to the database.
I have updated this in the corresponding GitHub Issue as well.

thanks @Sharad this.conn.isHealthy() is working fine for db connection existence. Can you guide me how to handle errors through event... I don't want to use try...cache method . . .

I believe this issue has been resolved on GitHub. Please Use isHealthy() method of the connection object.

Yes, we already discuss in details at ticket https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1681.
